# Possible to declare variable as a daterange data type

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

Is it possible to declare a variable as a daterange data type when writing a function?

I receive a syntax error at or near "daterange" for the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_example (p1 daterange, p2 integer, p3 text)
RETURNS integer as $value$
DECLARE
variable1 daterange := (SELECT...)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that creating the function in
    LANGUAGE sql
caused the issue.  When i changed it to
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
the daterange is recognized.  Sorry beginner mistake, LANGUAGE sql does not support variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like below:

```
create or replace function test()
returns void as
$Body$
Declare
       var1 daterange := (SELECT '(2010-01-01,2010-01-05)'::daterange);
Begin
       RAISE INFO '%',var1;
end;
$Body$
language plpgsql;

SELECT test()

OUTPUT :

[2010-01-02,2010-01-05)
```

For more info [**rangetypes**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/rangetypes.html)

Comment: Thanks Ilesh, unfortunately the error occurs between the variable (var1) and datatype (daterange), before the SELECT statement can be read.

Comment: I don't think the `select` is necessary (in fact I am not sure this is allowed inside the `declare` section). Just assign the value using `:=`